# Is it possible to get a remote resource by using this API: ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to get a remote resource by using this API: `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()`

For instance:
`ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("http://www.xxx.com/xx.txt");`

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream is meant for retrieving resources within your web-app and (unless I've misunderstood and you're trying to request a URL within your own application) that isn't true here.

You could just do something like:

```
     URL someUrl = new URL("http://some.link.com/");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(someUrl.openStream()));
               // do stuff with the input stream
     in.close();
```

Comment: The reason I asked that is because in the code, we read the path from request parameter. So, it would be very dangerous if anyone provide an remote URL.

Comment: From this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727898/fire-off-an-internal-servletrequest-in-tomcat) it sounds like there is no way to fire off a request, from within a servlet, to another URL within the same application. So for internal or external, I think you would have to implement something like my answer. But if you're worried about external links, you'd need to check for that.

Comment: If this answers the question, please consider accepting my answer, or give further feedback on what you're looking for/where the answer is incorrect. Thanks